# Console Tic-Tac-Toe game in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, tic-tac-toe

While having experience with other languages I only recently started learning Rust and I was hoping to get some feedback on my little beginner project, especially regarding style (stuff like too many functions, should rather be refactored into struct with methods, etc.) and safety (whether there are situations that could crash the program).

I already ran Clippy but intentionally ignored two warnings because I preferred my own solution.

One thing I'm already unsure of is the way I solved draws and wins as I find my current solution not really nice.

```rust
use std::{fmt, io};

fn main() {
    let mut field = [FieldState::Blank; 9];

    print_field(&field);
    loop {
        println!("Player 1 (X) take your turn");
        take_turn(FieldState::Player1, &mut field);
        print_field(&field);
        print_win(check_win(&field));
        print_draw(&field);

        println!("Player 2 (O) take your turn");
        take_turn(FieldState::Player2, &mut field);
        print_field(&field);
        print_win(check_win(&field));
        print_draw(&field);
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum FieldState {
    Blank,
    Player1,
    Player2,
}

impl fmt::Display for FieldState {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            FieldState::Blank => write!(f, " "),
            FieldState::Player1 => write!(f, "X"),
            FieldState::Player2 => write!(f, "O"),
        }
    }
}

fn print_field(field: &[FieldState; 9]) {
    for i in 0..2 {
        println!("{}|{}|{}", field[i * 3], field[1 + i * 3], field[2 + i * 3]);
        println!("-----");
    }
    println!("{}|{}|{}", field[2 * 3], field[1 + 2 * 3], field[2 + 2 * 3]);
}

fn take_turn(p: FieldState, f: &mut [FieldState; 9]) {
    loop {
        let choice = (read_user_input() - 1) as usize;

        if f[choice] != FieldState::Blank {
            println!("There's already a marking there! Pick another place.");
            continue;
        } else {
            f[choice] = p;
            return;
        }
    }
}

fn read_user_input() -> u8 {
    loop {
        let mut ans = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut ans)
            .expect("Failed to read input");

        let ans: i16 = match ans.trim().parse() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Please enter a number from 1 to 9");
                continue;
            }
        };

        if ans < 1 || ans > 9 {
            println!("Please enter a number from 1 to 9");
            continue;
        } else {
            return ans.try_into().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn check_win(f: &[FieldState; 9]) -> FieldState {
    // Columns
    for x in 0..3 {
        if f[x] != FieldState::Blank && f[x] == f[3 + x] && f[x] == f[6 + x] {
            return f[x];
        }
    }

    // Rows
    for y in 0..3 {
        if f[3 * y] != FieldState::Blank
            && f[3 * y] == f[1 + 3 * y]
            && f[3 * y] == f[2 + 3 * y]
        {
            return f[3 * y];
        }
    }

    // Diagonals
    if f[0] != FieldState::Blank && f[0] == f[4] && f[0] == f[8] {
        return f[0];
    }

    if f[2] != FieldState::Blank && f[2] == f[4] && f[0] == f[6] {
        return f[2];
    }

    FieldState::Blank
}

fn print_draw(f: &[FieldState; 9]) {
    for i in 0..9 {
        if f[i] == FieldState::Blank {
            return;
        }
    }

    println!("It's a draw!");
    std::process::exit(0);
}

fn print_win(winner: FieldState) {
    if winner == FieldState::Player1 {
        println!("Player 1 (X) won!");
        std::process::exit(0);
    } else if winner == FieldState::Player2 {
        println!("Player 2 (O) won!");
        std::process::exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bug

`check_win` contains a copy-paste error:

```rust
if f[2] != FieldState::Blank && f[2] == f[4] && f[0] == f[6] {
    return f[2]; //                             ^^^^ should be f[2]
}
```

## Simplify `check_win`

The logic for any group of three fields (column, row or diagonal) is the same: check if the first field isn't empty and if it equals the other two fields.
This can be extracted into a helper closure:

```rust
fn check_win(f: &[FieldState; 9]) -> FieldState {
    let check_group = |i1, i2, i3| f[i1] != FieldState::Blank && f[i1] == f[i2] && f[i1] == f[i3];
    
    // Columns
    for x in 0..3 {
        if check_group(x, 3 + x, 6 + x) {
            return f[x];
        }
    }

    // Rows
    for y in 0..3 {
        if check_group(3 * y, 1 + 3 * y, 2 + 3 * y) {
           return f[3 * y];
        }
    }

    // Diagonals
    if check_group(0, 4, 8) {
        return f[0];
    }

    if check_group(2, 4, 6) {
        return f[2];
    }

    FieldState::Blank
}
```

With this, such a copy-paste error is also less likely to happen.

## Integer type confusion

In `read_user_input`, you parse the input as an `i16`, then cast it to a `u8` and then cast it to a `usize` at the call site. Just use `usize` directly and avoid casting.
Further, the code to print the error message is repeated two times. Using a match guard makes this easier:

```rust
fn read_user_input() -> usize {
    loop {
        let mut ans = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut ans)
            .expect("Failed to read input");

        match ans.trim().parse::<usize>() {
            Ok(n) if (1..10).contains(&n) => return n,
            _ => println!("Please enter a number from 1 to 9"),
        }
    }
}
```

## Shorter `main`

With an extra variable `current_player` we can avoid duplicating the code for player 1 and 2:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut field = [FieldState::Blank; 9];
    let mut current_player = FieldState::Player1;

    print_field(&field);
    loop {
        if current_player == FieldState::Player1 {
            println!("Player 1 (X) take your turn");
        } else {
            println!("Player 2 (O) take your turn");
        }
        
        take_turn(current_player, &mut field);
        print_field(&field);
        print_win(check_win(&field));
        print_draw(&field);
        current_player = if current_player == FieldState::Player1 {
            FieldState::Player2
        } else {
            FieldState::Player1
        };
    }
}
```

This will come in handy for the next step.

## Usage of `std::process::exit`

You use this function in `print_draw` and `print_win`. The problem with it is that it makes your code extremely unflexible. Right now, if you wanted to do anything else after the end of the game, it wouldn't be possible. Let's change that by adding another `enum` to describe the game state:

```rust
enum GameState {
    Win,
    Draw,
    Running,
}
```

Then, we can extract the logic from `print_draw` and update `check_win` to instead return the current `GameState`:

```rust
fn get_game_state(f: &[FieldState; 9]) -> GameState {
    let check_group = |i1, i2, i3| f[i1] != FieldState::Blank && f[i1] == f[i2] && f[i1] == f[i3];

    // Columns
    for x in 0..3 {
        if check_group(x, 3 + x, 6 + x) {
            return GameState::Win;
        }
    }

    // Rows
    for y in 0..3 {
        if check_group(3 * y, 1 + 3 * y, 2 + 3 * y) {
            return GameState::Win;
        }
    }

    // Diagonals
    if check_group(0, 4, 8) || check_group(2, 4, 6) {
        return GameState::Win;
    }

    // Draw checking
    if f.contains(&FieldState::Blank) {
        return GameState::Running;
    }

    GameState::Draw
}
```

The code for draw checking was simplified a bit too.
Now, the updated `main` looks like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut field = [FieldState::Blank; 9];
    let mut current_player = FieldState::Player1;

    print_field(&field);
    loop {
        if current_player == FieldState::Player1 {
            println!("Player 1 (X) take your turn");
        } else {
            println!("Player 2 (O) take your turn");
        }

        take_turn(current_player, &mut field);
        print_field(&field);
        match get_game_state(&field) {
            GameState::Win => {
                print_winner(current_player);
                break;
            }
            GameState::Draw => {
                println!("It's a draw!");
                break;
            }
            GameState::Running => (),
        };

        current_player = if current_player == FieldState::Player1 {
            FieldState::Player2
        } else {
            FieldState::Player1
        };
    }
}
```

`print_draw` was inlined since its logic was extracted and only a single `println!` remained. `print_win` remains, but the `process::exit` calls are removed.

## Final code:

```rust
use std::{fmt, io};

fn main() {
    let mut field = [FieldState::Blank; 9];
    let mut current_player = FieldState::Player1;

    print_field(&field);
    loop {
        if current_player == FieldState::Player1 {
            println!("Player 1 (X) take your turn");
        } else {
            println!("Player 2 (O) take your turn");
        }

        take_turn(current_player, &mut field);
        print_field(&field);
        match get_game_state(&field) {
            GameState::Win => {
                print_winner(current_player);
                break;
            }
            GameState::Draw => {
                println!("It's a draw!");
                break;
            }
            GameState::Running => (),
        };

        current_player = if current_player == FieldState::Player1 {
            FieldState::Player2
        } else {
            FieldState::Player1
        };
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum FieldState {
    Blank,
    Player1,
    Player2,
}

impl fmt::Display for FieldState {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            FieldState::Blank => write!(f, " "),
            FieldState::Player1 => write!(f, "X"),
            FieldState::Player2 => write!(f, "O"),
        }
    }
}

enum GameState {
    Win,
    Draw,
    Running,
}

fn print_field(field: &[FieldState; 9]) {
    for i in 0..2 {
        println!("{}|{}|{}", field[i * 3], field[1 + i * 3], field[2 + i * 3]);
        println!("-----");
    }
    println!("{}|{}|{}", field[2 * 3], field[1 + 2 * 3], field[2 + 2 * 3]);
}

fn take_turn(p: FieldState, f: &mut [FieldState; 9]) {
    loop {
        let choice = read_user_input() - 1;

        if f[choice] != FieldState::Blank {
            println!("There's already a marking there! Pick another place.");
            continue;
        } else {
            f[choice] = p;
            return;
        }
    }
}

fn read_user_input() -> usize {
    loop {
        let mut ans = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut ans)
            .expect("Failed to read input");

        match ans.trim().parse::<usize>() {
            Ok(n) if (1..10).contains(&n) => return n,
            _ => println!("Please enter a number from 1 to 9"),
        }
    }
}

fn get_game_state(f: &[FieldState; 9]) -> GameState {
    let check_group = |i1, i2, i3| f[i1] != FieldState::Blank && f[i1] == f[i2] && f[i1] == f[i3];

    // Columns
    for x in 0..3 {
        if check_group(x, 3 + x, 6 + x) {
            return GameState::Win;
        }
    }

    // Rows
    for y in 0..3 {
        if check_group(3 * y, 1 + 3 * y, 2 + 3 * y) {
            return GameState::Win;
        }
    }

    // Diagonals
    if check_group(0, 4, 8) || check_group(2, 4, 6) {
        return GameState::Win;
    }

    // Draw checking
    if f.contains(&FieldState::Blank) {
        return GameState::Running;
    }

    GameState::Draw
}

fn print_winner(winner: FieldState) {
    if winner == FieldState::Player1 {
        println!("Player 1 (X) won!");
    } else {
        println!("Player 2 (O) won!");
    }
}
```

## Further ideas:

### Different purposes of `FieldState`

`FieldState` is used both to store the state of the field and to store the current player. But since the current player can never be `FieldState::Blank`, consider removing that variant from the enum and renaming it to `enum Player`. The fields can then be stored as an `Option<Player>`.

### Game struct

I agree with your thought of using a struct for this. It improves reusability and makes the code easier to use. Here's a possibility how to define one:

```rust
struct Game {
    fields: [Option<Player>; 9],
    current_player: Player,
}
```

We should also add a constructor:

```rust
impl Game {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            fields: [None; 9],
            current_player: Player::Player1,
        }
    }
}
```

You could then turn most functions into methods of this struct.